# Reference and access Excel from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update an Excel file from Outlook (Office 2010). How do I reference and access Excel?

As a simple test I'm trying to count the number of open workbooks. When I run this I get 0, even though there are 2 open.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWBook As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Debug.Print "xlApp.Workbooks.Count = " & xlApp.Workbooks.Count

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlWBook = xlApp.Workbooks("Data.xlsx")
    Err.Clear 'Clear error and open File Index

    If  xlWBook Is Nothing Then
        Set xlWBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Data.xlsx")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are creating a new Excel instance - which is separate to the one or more instances (containing your open two workbooks)

Comment: Sounds like a messy way to operate. Better to open the workbooks you need in a (new) instance of Excel that your code owns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use to detect Excel:

```
Dim xlApp As excel.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then 'Excel not running
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

once xlApp is set, you can use `xlApp.Workbooks.Count` to count the worksheets

Note: This code will get the first one opened, if there are more than one instance of Excel to find

If you have to find a specific workbook, from [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902), `Set xlApp = GetObject("Book2").Application` will find the workbook, even if it's not in the first instance. If the workbook is from a file, or already saved, replace `book2` with the **full** path and filename - **Side effect** - this will also *open* the file if it is not already open
More usage info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164798%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: This won't work if there is more than 1 existing instance of Excel open

Comment: True, but I use this code trying not to open any more instances than I need to

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I've never used the GetObject and SetObject - but they are now added to my repertoire. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I see. That gets the first instance of Excel. So if Data.xlsx is open in any other instance, I will not see it. Is there a way around this? I need to account for any eventuality...

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902 - from this page, `Set xlApp = GetObject("Book2").Application` will find the workbook, even if it's not in the first instance

Comment: moved my previous comment to the answer

Comment: @Sean: Am I missing something? From the same link that you posted: `If multiple instances of Microsoft Excel are running, GetObject attaches to the instance that is launched first. If you then close the first instance, another call to GetObject attaches to the second instance that was launched, and so forth.`

Comment: if you use the `Set xlApp = GetObject("Book2").Application` instead of the `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` then it will attach to the correct instance

Comment: Have you tested the above code with two different instances of Excel? I am not able to get it work...

Comment: you have to use either the "book" name if not saved, or the full path if it is, otherwise it can cause issues. I've switched back and forth between 3 different instances using that method

Comment: `or the full path if it is...` + 1 Ah! I was just using the name. Nice catch! You might want to add this additonal info in your above post?

Comment: Perhaps we are causing a problem with our solution on top of a solution. It looks like `Set xlApp = GetObject("C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\File Index.xlsx").Application` creates an instance of the file passed. I'm getting 0 error when I run that line, regardless of if the file is open or not. @SeanCheshire @SiddharthRout